# C# Entity Framework - How to return a list with Max value?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

To start, I have a database modeled using the Entity Framework with the following structure:

```
Pedidos :
--------
IDPedidoDetalhe (int, not null)
IDPedido  (int, not null)
Aditamento (int, not null)
Semana  (int, null)
Ano  (int, null)
Titulo  (nvarchar(250), null)
```

I'm trying to create a query that finds the line of the table with the "IDPedido" required and the max value for "Aditamento". To find the max value for a required item (npedido), i use:

```
List<Pedidos> lista = db.Pedidos.Where(m => m.IDPedido == npedido).ToList();
var pedido = lista.Select(m => m.Aditamento).Max(x => x);
```

But I want the line in the list (all the columns) and no just the value for "Aditamento".

Can you help me, with this query?

Comment: It should be list or single entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loosing all fields of Pedido entity when you are doing projection to Aditamento with `Select(m => m.Aditamento)`. For getting single Pedido by id, with max Aditamento value you should simply order filtered Pedidos by Aditamento and select first one:

```
var pedido = db.Pedidos.Where(p => p.IDPedido == npedido)
               .OrderByDescending(p => p.Aditamento)
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

For getting all Pedidos with max Aditamento value you need to group filtered Pedidos by Aditamento and select group with max key value:

```
var pedidos = db.Pedidos.Where(p => p.IDPedido == npedido)
                .GroupBy(p => p.Aditamento)
                .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you want list, then check if you have found any pedidos by id and convert group to list:

```
if (pedidos != null)
{
    List<Pedido> result = pedidos.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
List<Pedidos> lista = db.Pedidos.Where(m => m.IDPedido == npedido).ToList();

var maxValue= lista.Max(x => x.Aditamento);

// IEnumerable with all lines that have the "maxValue"
var lineWithMaxValue = lista.Where(x => x.Aditamento == maxValue);
```